# TextFieldWidget not working with FabricMC (Java)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Recently I've been trying to learn some stuff about Minecraft Modding. I've chosen to use ***[Fabric Mod Loader](https://fabricmc.net)*** to make/test mods I'm making.

In doing so, I've working on a recent project (more like test) and it has to do with screens. So enough about that and on to the problem.

So I've made a text field and for some reason the text in it isn't showing up when I type..
***Video of the problem:*** https://streamable.com/ik7j79
***The Code:*** https://pastebin.com/8XtSGpWj

```java
package battledash2.clientcommands.screens;

import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.rendering.v1.HudRenderCallback;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.font.TextRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.Screen;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.ButtonWidget;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.widget.TextFieldWidget;
import net.minecraft.client.util.math.MatrixStack;
import net.minecraft.text.*;
import net.minecraft.util.Formatting;

import java.util.logging.LogManager;

public class GuiScreen extends Screen {
    public GuiScreen(Text title) {
        super(title);
    }

    protected void init() {
        // init

        System.out.println("Loading Screen");
    }

    public void render(MatrixStack matrices, int mouseX, int mouseY, float delta) {
        matrices.push();
        renderBackground(matrices);

        /*
         * this.addButton(new ButtonWidget(this.width / 2 - 102, this.height / 4 + 24 + -16, 204, 20, new TranslatableText("menu.returnToGame"), (buttonWidgetx) -> {
         *          this.client.openScreen((Screen)null);
         *          this.client.mouse.lockCursor();
         *       }));
         */

        TextFieldWidget textfield = new TextFieldWidget(textRenderer, this.width / 2 - 102, this.height / 4 + 24 + -16, 204, 20, new LiteralText("Chat message").setStyle(Style.EMPTY.withColor(Formatting.WHITE)));

        this.addButton(textfield);

        ButtonWidget submit = new ButtonWidget(this.width / 2 - 102, (this.height / 4 + 24 + -16)+(this.height / 4 + 24 + -16)+10, 204, 20, new LiteralText("Send chat message"), button->{
            String message = textfield.getText();

            MinecraftClient.getInstance().openScreen((Screen) null);
            MinecraftClient.getInstance().mouse.lockCursor();

            MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.sendChatMessage(message);
        });
        this.addButton(submit);

        // drawTextWithShadow(matrices, textRenderer, new LiteralText("Chat message").setStyle(Style.EMPTY.withColor(Formatting.WHITE)), 10, 10, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        matrices.pop();
        super.render(matrices, mouseX, mouseY, delta);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found out the problem. It was because I was putting the widgets in the "render" method. I created a new method called "initWidgets" and ran `initWidgets()` in the main method and then moved the widgets to the "initWidgets" method and it worked.